# Location of Open Source Documents for CX20 Drone

Tags: distribution

I am not sure if this is one of the purposes of this site, if not, please remove/move to the correct site.

I recently bought a CX20 drone that was said to be open source.  I have not been able to find the CAD files or software anywhere.  Is there a standard location that this data is kept for open source projects?

[Here is a link to the product.](http://www.banggood.com/Cheerson-CX20-Opensource-Version-AutoPathfinder-Quadcopter-RTF-p-932145.html?p=US21043131592013105M)

Comment: The first place to ask would be the store you bought it from. But there's a chance someone else might know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no standard for publishing/archiving source code for an open source project. Many organizations use a public repository (e.g. GitHub), others provide access via a download from their site. It is also common to include the source with the install/binaries (e.g. .zip file) or on any distributed media with a product.

The Open Source Initiative, the stewards of the Open Source Definition, and an internationally recognized authority in open source standards and practices, requires access to un-obfuscated source code. So if the organization distributing the software is claiming that that software is open source, they must provide you the source.

A suggestion for your specific case would be to simply contact the company that sold it to you (as @curiousdannii mentioned).

Answer (score 3):

Cheeson violates our open source license that we have on ArduPilot and unfortunately they have not published their files. You can find out more about the original files at http://ardupilot.com/

Comment: Thanks for this answer and welcome to the site! Sorry to hear about your stuff being used in violation of the license you provided. Have you considered contacting the FSF?http://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/52/what-can-should-i-do-when-i-see-a-violation-to-gpl-restrictions May be relevant.

Comment: @Martijn, unless OP gave the rights to the FSF, they have no standing. They *might* want to/be able to point in the right direction, but no guarantee.

Comment: @vonbrand they have no standing, but they do give assistance, even if they can't sue themselves, and help with the options available.

Comment: Even lacking standing, there are other benefits - seeking legal advice re: what sort of recompense/redress is available as @Martijn said. Perhaps, more importantly they'll have access to expert witnesses (RMS drafted the darned license after all), have garnered respect of the courts s.t any of their _amicus curiae_, will lend gravity, and finally will have the institutional knowledge w/r/t the latest case law. ("_ v _ 20__, ruled 9-0 [a binding authority] with a unanimous opinion relevant to your __ argument; or the 9th circuit had a *very* similar argument and has persuasive authority)